# Increment Operator in Javascript not incrementing the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array in which I stored 7 images as numbers. I want these images to change at regular intervals. But, the increment operator seems to be not working. Please provide me a solution.

My code is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
      i = 0;
      setInterval(function(){
         $('main').css('background-image', function(){
            for(i; i <= 7; i++){

            return( 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)');

         }

      });
     }, 5000);

  })
```

and what i get after this is "images/main-bg1.jpg" always against incremented images like"main-bg2, main-bg3" after five seconds. what may be the issue?

Comment: you forgot to define i as var on line no 3
 use 
var i = 0;

Comment: @aM-Vee Actually, there is no point in declaring `i` outside the loop.  Also, you have an off-by-one error, as pointed out by @Jeff Watkins. Use `for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++)`. And the problem is that you `return` from within the loop meaning that the very first iteration interrupts the loop and exits the function.

Comment: Declare i variables datatype as var eg: var i=0;

Comment: is this guy downvoting all answers? hell I' aint answering .

Comment: whats the point of your function???, even if you get it working its gonna go so fast you will only see the last image.

Comment: @Tasos: SO is an English site. Please stick to English.

Comment: American, English, whatever. Neither is anywhere close to Greek.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a `url` before the `for` loop can do anything.

This is what you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        $('main').css('background-image', function(){
            i = (++i % 7);
            return( 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)');
        });
    }, 5000);
})
```

The "magic" happens at `i = (++i % 7);`
That line increments `i` by `1`, each time the interval executes the function, and resets `i` back to `1`, when it was `6`. (arrays are zero-indexed in JS)

Comment: that did it. Thank you @Cerbrus. But can I go back to the 1st image  once the loop is completed.? when it comes to first image it shows "undefined".

Comment: @CodeName44: My code already does that. The `% 7` in `i = (++i % 7);` resets the variable to `0`, as soon as it gets to `7`.

Comment: when it comes to first image after loop, it shows "main-bgundefined.jpg". what could be the problem?

Comment: @CodeName44: Can you double-check that line before the `return`, with my answer?

Comment: Yes I did and what happens now is dat, script is picking only odd values. not the images with even index.!!

        $(document).ready(function(){
 var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 i = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
  $('main').css('background-image', function(){
   i = (++i % 7) + 1; 
    return( 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)');

  });
  }, 5000);
 
})

Comment: You've got `i = (++i % 7) + 1` in there. That should be `i = (++i % 7)` (remove the `+1`)

Comment: Yes, Did it. But now in the first loop, code picks only odd values and in the next iteration, picks only even indexes.!!!

Comment: Is your code still cached in the browser? That behavior is pretty much impossible.

Comment: That did the trick. Everything works fine now. Thank you @Cerbrus

Answer (score 1):

There are seven elements in your array and your counter will loop eight times 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 as your conditional is <= 7. This will be causing you an issue.

Also you should declare i, probably in the for loop rather than outside e.g.

```
for (var i =0; i < 7; i++)
```

Finally, you're "returning" mid loop.

```
return( 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)');
```

This will not work.

What you probably want is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function(){
     $('main').css('background-image', function(){
        var img = 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)';
        i++;
        if ( i > 6) {
          i = 0;
        }
        return(img);
     }
  });
 }, 5000);
```

})

Comment: Take a look at your code, what will happen when `i == 7`?

Comment: Oops, sorry, that's what you get for not writing unit tests ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need not to use `for` loop, just increment `i` inside setInterval

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var img_array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
      i = 0;
      var len = img_array.length;
      setInterval(function(){
         $('main').css('background-image', function(){
            return( 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)');
         });
         //increment here
         i++;
         // if variable value equal to array length then reset 'i'
         if(i==len)i=0;
     }, 5000);

  });
```

Comment: Now, take a look at your code, what will happen when `i == 7`?

Comment: for `i=7`, it will return image and then `i++` i.e. `i==8` and it will reset `i=0;`

Comment: What is the _exact_ string `return( 'url(images/main-bg' + img_array[i] + '.jpg)');` will return when `i` is `7`, then?

Comment: @Cerbus, yeah but `for(i; i <= 7; i++)` this for loop (As OP posted) says it required `i<=7`, it means i through 0 to 7, right?

Comment: Have a look at the array, how many elements does it have? Sure, `<= 7` is what the OP wrote in the for loop, but that might be wrong ;-)

Comment: oh ... I did not notice that.. let me correct it then :)